# InvalidArgumentException: Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App\Routedata]

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

This is my function

```
public function create($alias, $profileId)
    {
        $this->setClientAndClientProfile($alias, $profileId);

        return view('client.data.map')->with('client', $this->client)->with('clientProfile', $this->clientProfile);
    }
```

and this is test that i write it

```
public function createTest()
    {
        $this->Data = factory(App\Data::class)->create([
            'id' => '1',
            'client' => 'first',
            ' name' => 'name1',
            'Status' => ''

        ]);
       $this->be($this->$RouteForecast);
       $this->visit('/backend/data')

        ->seePageIs('/backend/data');

    }
```

when i run i got this error

```
InvalidArgumentException: Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App\Data].
```

how i can solve this problem ?

Comment: Do you have an entry in the `database/factories/ModelFactory.php` file with the `App\Data::class`?

Comment: this is my modeFactory

$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'email' => $faker->email,
        'password' => bcrypt(str_random(10)),
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});

Comment: So thats your error. You should have another block of code with something like `$factory->define(App\Data::class, function(Faker\Generator $faker) {...})`

Answer (score 0):

In my case was:

`phpunit --version
PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.`

I had this problem in laravel 5.5. But in my composer.json it was 6.4. This means I have another phpunit path with an older version. It was in Xampp/php/phpunit file. Laravel's phpunit is 'vendor/bin/phpunit'. So I tried this:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\www\blog\vendor\bin\phpunit --version
PHPUnit 6.4.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

Voila!